# Expand rows between begin date and exit date and count the number of days in R

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data, tidy

I have a dataset in which each row is a minister ID, for each row I have columns with the date (day, month, and year) the minister entered the government (begin) and exit the government (exit). This is a sample on how it looks like right now: 
[image: Original]

```
data <- structure(list(id_min = c("1030015", "1030028"), begin_day = c("29", 
"4"), begin_month = c("12", "1"), begin_year = c("2019", "2020"
), exit_day = c("3", "10"), exit_month = c("1", "1"), exit_year = c("2020", 
"2020")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

I want to expand the rows between the "begin date" and "exit date", and also create a new column (number_days) counting the number of days the minister was in the government. The other variables in the dataset (omitted here) should just be repeated in the expanded version of the data). This is the data frame output I am looking for: 
[image: Output dataframe]

I was able to put the dates together in the format %Y-%m-%d, and create the new column "number_days" with the following codes

```
data$begin_date <- as.Date(with(data, paste(begin_year, begin_month, begin_day,sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
data$exit_date <- as.Date(with(data, paste(exit_year, exit_month, exit_day,sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
data$number_days <- data$exit_date - data$begin_date
```

But I am not having success expanding the rows between the two dates (begin_date and exit_date). I was trying to do it using `tidyr::complete()`.

Comment: Hi Thiago, you're attracting downvotes and close votes because you've included your sample data as an image and you've not shown any code you've tried thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is with the `uncount` function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>% 
  mutate(start_date = mdy(paste(begin_month,begin_day,begin_year,sep="-")),
         end_date = mdy(paste(exit_month,exit_day,exit_year,sep="-")),
         number_days = as.integer(end_date-start_date + 1)) %>%
  uncount(as.integer(number_days)) %>%
  group_by(id_min) %>%
  mutate(begin_day = day(seq(start_date[1], end_date[1], by = "days")),
         begin_month = month(seq(start_date[1], end_date[1], by = "days")),
         begin_year = year(seq(start_date[1], end_date[1], by = "days"))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-start_date, -end_date)
# A tibble: 13 x 8
# Groups:   id_min [2]
   id_min  begin_day begin_month begin_year exit_day exit_month exit_year number_days
   <chr>       <int>       <int>      <int> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>           <int>
 1 1030015        29          12       2019 3        1          2020                6
 2 1030015        30          12       2019 3        1          2020                6
 3 1030015        31          12       2019 3        1          2020                6
 4 1030015         1           1       2020 3        1          2020                6
 5 1030015         2           1       2020 3        1          2020                6
 6 1030015         3           1       2020 3        1          2020                6
 7 1030028         4           1       2020 10       1          2020                7
 8 1030028         5           1       2020 10       1          2020                7
 9 1030028         6           1       2020 10       1          2020                7
10 1030028         7           1       2020 10       1          2020                7
11 1030028         8           1       2020 10       1          2020                7
12 1030028         9           1       2020 10       1          2020                7
13 1030028        10           1       2020 10       1          2020                7
```

Answer (score 4):

A `tidyverse` solution :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  #Combine begin columns to have start_day
  unite(start_day, begin_year, begin_month, begin_day, sep = '-', remove = FALSE) %>%
  #Combine exit columns to have end_day
  unite(end_day, exit_year, exit_month, exit_day, sep = '-', remove = FALSE) %>%
  #Convert to date
  mutate_at(vars(start_day, end_day), as.Date) %>%
  #Count number of days between them
  mutate(number_days = as.integer(end_day - start_day) + 1) %>%
  #Create a sequence between two dates 
  mutate(date = map2(start_day, end_day, seq, by = 'day')) %>%
  #Add the data in long format
  unnest(date) %>%
  #separate date into year, month and date.
  separate(date, c('begin_year', 'begin_month', 'begin_day'), sep = '-') %>%
  select(-start_day, -end_day)


# A tibble: 13 x 8
#   id_min  exit_day exit_month exit_year number_days begin_year begin_month begin_day
#   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>      <chr>           <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>    
# 1 1030015 3        1          2020                6 2019       12          29       
# 2 1030015 3        1          2020                6 2019       12          30       
# 3 1030015 3        1          2020                6 2019       12          31       
# 4 1030015 3        1          2020                6 2020       01          01       
# 5 1030015 3        1          2020                6 2020       01          02       
# 6 1030015 3        1          2020                6 2020       01          03       
# 7 1030028 10       1          2020                7 2020       01          04       
# 8 1030028 10       1          2020                7 2020       01          05       
# 9 1030028 10       1          2020                7 2020       01          06       
#10 1030028 10       1          2020                7 2020       01          07       
#11 1030028 10       1          2020                7 2020       01          08       
#12 1030028 10       1          2020                7 2020       01          09       
#13 1030028 10       1          2020                7 2020       01          10
```

Comment: Which package within the `tidyverse` contains `unite()`? I'm not familiar with that one.

Comment: @Wil `unite` is in `tidyr`. @Ian Campbell I have number of days column there called `number_days`, is that what you meant ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fill_gaps()` function from the `tsibble` package as well.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(
    exit_date = as.Date(paste(exit_year, exit_month, exit_day, sep = "-")),
    begin_date = as.Date(paste(begin_year, begin_month, begin_day, sep = "-")),
    number_days = as.numeric(exit_date - begin_date) + 1
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("date"), names_to = "event",values_to = "date") %>%
  as_tsibble(key = id_min, index = date) %>%
  fill_gaps() %>%
  mutate(begin_day = format(date, "%d"),
         begin_month = format(date, "%m"),
         begin_year = format(date, "%Y")) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(-event, -date) %>%
  fill(everything())

# A tibble: 13 x 8
   id_min  begin_day begin_month begin_year exit_day exit_month exit_year number_days
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>       <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>
 1 1030015 29        12          2019       3        1          2020                6
 2 1030015 30        12          2019       3        1          2020                6
 3 1030015 31        12          2019       3        1          2020                6
 4 1030015 01        01          2020       3        1          2020                6
 5 1030015 02        01          2020       3        1          2020                6
 6 1030015 03        01          2020       3        1          2020                6
 7 1030028 04        01          2020       10       1          2020                7
 8 1030028 05        01          2020       10       1          2020                7
 9 1030028 06        01          2020       10       1          2020                7
10 1030028 07        01          2020       10       1          2020                7
11 1030028 08        01          2020       10       1          2020                7
12 1030028 09        01          2020       10       1          2020                7
13 1030028 10        01          2020       10       1          2020                7
```